# change password in codeigniter with logged in users throws error

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to change the password for logged in users,but it always give me an error:[Message: Trying to get property 'password' of non-object] in the controller. How to solve this error???
Please help,Thanks much!

This is my controller:

```
                    if($this->form_validation->run()){
                    $cur_password = md5($this->input->post('cpassword')); // md5-encrypt the password
                    $new_password = md5($this->input->post('npassword'));
                    $conf_password = md5($this->input->post('copassword'));
                    //$this->load->model('queries');
                    $this->load->library('session');
                    $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');//multiple users id login

                    $passwd = $this->queries->getCurPassword($user_id);
 !ERROR FOUND HERE!->if($passwd->password == $cur_password){
                        if($new_password == $conf_password){
                            if($this->queries->updatePassword($new_password,$user_id)){
                                echo 'Password Updated Successfully!';
                                echo '<br/><label><a href="'.base_url().'main/enter">Back to homepage</a></label><br/>';
                            }else{
                                echo 'Failed To Update Password!!';
                            }
                        }else{
                            echo 'New Password and Confirm Password is not matching!!';
                        }

                    }else{
                        echo 'Sorry! Current Password is not matching!!';
                    }
                }else{
                    echo validation_errors();

                }
```

This is my model:

```
<?php
class Queries extends CI_Model{

function login() {
    $query = $this->db->select('*')
                      ->from('users')
                      ->where('id');
    return $query->row();
}

function index() {
    $userid = $this->login()->id; //id of the user which is currently logged IN
    $this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $user_id);
}
    public function getCurPassword($user_id){   
        $query = $this->db->where(['id'=>$user_id])
                          ->get('users');
        if($query->num_rows() > 0 ){
            return $query->row();
        }
    }
    public function updatePassword($new_password,$user_id){
        $data = array(
                      //'password' => md5($this->input->post("$new_password"))
                      'password' => ($new_password)
                     //'password'=> password_hash(["$new_password"],PASSWORD_BCRYPT)
                      );
        return $this->db->where('id',$user_id)
        ->update('users',$data);
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: could you please post the full error message especially the part which mentions where in your code the error was raised?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: @jovan2226 Did you succeed solving the issue?

Comment: @David Winder  i got an error:[Unknown column 'user_name' in 'where clause'

SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_name` = 'admin']

Comment: @jovan2226 - As I said, I assume your DB has column name `user_name`, what is the scheme of your `users` table? do you have a user name "admin"? please respond in the chat-link given by @Samuel in my answer comments

Comment: Please check my updated answer @jovan2226

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the `user_id` not found.

Notice that the `getCurPassword` function will return the user if found (when checking if `num_rows > 0`) but if didn't found it returns `NULL`.

When this happens the `$passwd` var is null so you cann't access `$passwd->password`.

You can solve it by changing the `if` statement to:

```
if($passwd && $passwd->password == $cur_password){
```

**Edited** Try to retrieve your user name as and then call with it the `getCurPassword` function:

```
$user_name = $this->session->userdata('username');
$passwd = $this->queries->getCurPassword($user_name );
```

And in the controller change `getCurPassword` function as:

```
public function getCurPassword($user_name){   
    $query = $this->db->select('*')
              ->from('users')
              ->where('username', $user_name);
    if($query->num_rows() > 0 ){
        return $query->row();
    }
}
```

Notice that I assume you have "username" column in your DB

Comment: @jovan2226 sorry for the late answer. I think I got syntax error in the query of `getCurPassword` - I edited the answer. If it is still relevant you can check again

Answer (score 1):

You have error in your syntax error says that you are trying to get property of `non-object` means `$passwd` may be an array

```cpp
if($passwd['password'] == $cur_password)
```

And in case you have null `user_id`

Place these two lines in your controller function above `if($this->form_validation->run()){` line

```cpp
$userid = $this->queries->login()->id; //id of the user which is currently logged IN
$this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $userid);
```

and in your login function in model

```cpp
function login() {
$query = $this->db->select('*')
                  ->from('users')
                  ->where('username',$this->session->userdata('username'));
return $query->row();
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Not true. if  `$passwd` was an array then accessing with `['key']` is legit

Comment: @DavidWinder In question there is `$passwd->password` so its throwing error

Comment: Sorry you are correct - but I don't think that his problem. He sending null user_id to get the password...

Comment: @DavidWinder True. That too may be the issue.

Comment: keep showing error on this line:[$userid = $this->queries->login()->id;]